# Deserialize JSON string into String Array

Tags: java, json

How to get this string and put into String Array or HashMap? Any reference?

```
     {
        "code" : 403,
            "errors" : [ {
                "domain" : "global",
                "location" : "Authorization",
                "locationType" : "header",
                "message" : "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps",
                "reason" : "domainPolicy"
            } ],
        "message" : "The domain policy has disabled third-party Drive apps"
     }
```

====

This is my solution for Jackson:

```
public class TheErrorModel {
    public int code; 
    public Collection<Error> errors; 
    public String message;

    public TheErrorModel() {
    }

    public TheErrorModel(String json) 
            throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TheErrorModelother = mapper.readValue(json, TheErrorModel.class);

        this.code = other.code;
        this.errors = other.errors;
        this.message = other.message;
    }
}

class Error {
    public String domain;
    public String location;
    public String locationType; 
    public String message;
    public String reason;
}

TheErrorModel theErrorModel = new TheErrorModel(json);
```

So I get something like theErrorModel.message :D

Comment: There are plenty of libs available online. Have you tried any?

Comment: I have Jackson but I don't know what is the idea to use it :/

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use GSON http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ , It is pretty simple to use. You should just create class structure for this json schema.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
class YourErrorsJSON{
  private String domain 
  private String location;
  private String locationType; 
  private String message; 
  private String reason 
}

class YourJSON {
  private int code; 
  private YourErrorsJSON[] errors; 
  private String message;
}
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourJSON obj = gson.fromJson(json, YourJSON.class);
```

Comment: btw, that message is just an error I am not sure the author really want s to parse it. Maybe just substring for error is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
JSONObject yourObj = JSONObject.fromString(input_string);
String code = yourObj.get("code"); // code will have a value 403
```

Comment: what is the library for JSONObject? org.json.JSONObject?

Comment: you just need to include::

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

Comment: :/ i don't have that library... well let me check what can jackson provide first. thanks